# Fitting subgroup of any group is locally nilpotent

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotence, infinite-groups

Is it true that the Fitting subgroup of any group is locally nilpotent?

I know that if $G$ is finite then $F(G)$ is nilpotent and so locally nilpotent. Also, if $G$ is infinite then there's exists examples of infinite groups such that $F(G)$ is not nilpotent. So I was wondering if $F(G)$ is locally nilpotent no matter what the group $G$ is.

In order to show such result we need to prove that every finitely generated subgroup $\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\rangle$ of $F(G)$ is nilpotent. If I could show that for every $1\leq i\leq k$ there exists a nilpotent normal subgroup of $G$, say $N_i$, such that $x_i\in N_i$, then we would have
$$
   \langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\rangle \leqslant N_1N_2\ldots N_k \leqslant F(G)
$$
and then $\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\rangle$ would be nilpotent by Fitting's Theorem. But I don't know if this is possible to be demonstrated.

Comment: See Derek Holt's example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423830/fitting-subgroups-of-infinite-groups?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks! But this example shows that $F(G)$ can be a non-nilpotent group, which is something I'm already aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that by $F(G)$ you mean the subgroup generated by all normal nilpotent subgroups of $G$.

Every element of $F(G)$ can be written as a product of some generators, so any $x \in F(G)$ is contained in $\langle N_1, \ldots, N_k \rangle$ for some nilpotent normal subgroups $N_1$, $\ldots$, $N_k \trianglelefteq G$.

Thus any finitely generated subgroup of $F(G)$ is contained in $\langle N_1, \ldots, N_k \rangle$ for some nilpotent normal subgroups $N_1$, $\ldots$, $N_k \trianglelefteq G$. So $F(G)$ is locally nilpotent.

Comment: I think I got it: By definition, $F(G) = \langle \bigcup_{\lambda} N_\lambda\rangle$. Set $X:= \bigcup_{\lambda} N_\lambda$. If $g\in F(G)$ then by the definition of a subgroup generated by a subset, we have $g=g_1^{\pm 1}\ldots g_n^{\pm 1}$ where $g_i\in X$ and $n \geq 0$. So for each $i$ we have $g_i\in N_j$ for some $j$. Applying this argument for each generator of $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_k\rangle$ we will obtain a (finite) collection of subgroups $N_1,\ldots,N_r$ such that $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_k\rangle \leqslant N_1\ldots N_r$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the idea.